# Django forms with total calculation

Tags: javascript, django-forms

I am willing to create a form where users can place dimensions of boxes and the forms returns the total volume. This form then is sent and received with all details including the totals calculated.
Is this possible?

Comment: would you like to calculate a value and show them immediately in client side? In this case, there is no django-specific. You can just write some simple js code.

Comment: no actually I would like the result is submitted with other datas in the form..